# How to specify number of times a test should be run in BUILD file

Tags: googletest, bazel

I have an unit test which tests some code that is multi-threaded. While I was writing this code I used the following command many times

```
bazel test //xyz:my_test --runs_per_test 1000
```

This exposed some concurrency issues which I have now fixed. I want to add this `--runs_per_test` value to my test definition in my BUILD file, so that the night build (jenkins) runs this test multiple times. How do I do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a better hack.

As my tests are C++ [google tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/primer.md); google tests accept a flag `--gtest_repeat` for repeatedly running the test; I could pass this flag to the test from the bazel BUILD file, in the `args` attribute

```
cc_test(
    size = "small",
    name = "my_test",
    srcs = [".."],
    deps = [".."],
    args = ["--gtest_repeat=10"],
)
```

The problem with this approach is bazel would treat all the runs as a single test, so the run time would be cumulative of all runs. If this becomes more than the time limit for the test size (`small` in this example), then bazel would terminate the test!

Answer (score 1):

You can’t.
I suggest submitting a feature request over at https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hacky workaround using a `sh_test` wrapper, assuming you have a `cc_test` target. I'm using Bazel's own `//examples/cpp/` as an example:

```python
# Test to run multiple times
cc_test(
    name = "hello-fail_test",
    srcs = ["hello-fail.cc"],
    deps = [":hello-lib"],
)

# Wrapper to run test multiple times
sh_test(
    name = "repeated_hello-fail_test",
    srcs = ["hello-fail.sh"],
    data = [":hello-fail_test"],
)
```

And in `hello-fail.sh`, run the test in a for-loop and decide what you wish to do on test failure:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

WORKSPACE="$TEST_SRCDIR/io_bazel"

# Or count the number of successes/fails
# SUCCESS_COUNT=0
# FAIL_COUNT=0

for i in {1..3} # set the number of runs
do
    $WORKSPACE/examples/cpp/hello-fail_test
    if [ $? = 1 ]; then
        exit 1 # fail immediately, or increment test failure count
    fi
done

exit 0
```

Comment: I could as well write a shell script to remove bazel out of the picture altogether! Or go back to make... :)

Comment: Like @Ittai said, this isn't possible currently using native BUILD file semantics. Instead, this is a workaround that still utilizes Bazel's test mechanisms, including test caching because the actual test is a data dependency of the `sh_test` rule.

Comment: Curious: Jin just spent some time to help you and instead of being respectful you were snarky. Please be cool next time :)